# How do I hide a file inside an image with Python?

Tags: python, image, file, security, steganography

I know it's possible in Batch using the 'copy' command with the '/B' switch, i.e.:

```
copy /B imagefile+hiddenfile newfile
```

My question is this; Is it possible to do this in Python, and if so, how?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642361/hide-tar-file-in-png) is very similar, and it's answer is acceptable, but I am still curious;

Is there a way to do this without the stepic module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need stepic for that.

```
>>> out = file("out.jpg", "wb")
>>> out.write(file("someimage.jpg", "rb").read())
>>> out.write(file("somehiddenfile.pdf", "rb").read())
>>> out.close()
```

stepic is something completely different it is for putting "really" hidden data into an image, whereas your `copy` approach (and also my snippet above) just appends the file after the image's data. It is quite easy to extract the "somehiddenfile.pdf" from the generated file, whereas extracting steganographic information out of a real image is a lot more difficult.

Comment: Great answer! But how would we now extract the pdf appended in the image data? What would be the code for that?

Answer (score 1):

`stepic` is a python package written to perform this operation - why not simply [look at the source](http://domnit.org/stepic/stepic.py)?