# how to hide a txt file into a picture without stegano module?

Tags: python, image, file, security, steganography

i want to hide a .txt file to a picture, but i don't want to using stegano because i already use it and if i using the stegano again it will overwrite the data.
so i wanna used something like [How do I hide a file inside an image with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269923/how-do-i-hide-a-file-inside-an-image-with-python)

and i tried using the answer on that questions

```
out=file("makan.png","wb")
out.write(file("sudah.png","rb").read())
out.write(file("cipher.txt","rb").read())
out.close()
```

but it says file is not defined, can anyone explain this?
im beginner in python im so sorry

Comment: On what line do you have this error?

Comment: @Alderven the programs say the file is no defined, in line 'out=file("makan.png","wb")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `file` with `open`. Also you can use `with` so you don't need to call `close` at the end:

```
with open('makan.png', 'wb') as out:
    out.write(open('sudah.png', 'rb').read())
    out.write(open('cipher.txt', 'rb').read())
```

Extracting text from image:

```
with open('makan.png', 'rb') as f:
    text = f.read().split(b'IEND\xaeB`\x82')[1].decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: it work thank, but the problem how to change it back or to decrypt it? and the picture data seems decreasin is it okay?

Comment: See my updated answer. Also image size is increasing for me.